# Why returning by reference is faster than returning by value?

Tags: c++, reference, return-by-reference

```
class A
{
    int x,y;
    public:
       A(int a=0,int b=0)
       {x=a;y=b;}
    /* ... */
}

A& fctr()
{
    A loc(1,2);
    return loc;
}
```

Let's examine this instruction :

```
A x=fctr();
```

`fctr()` returning a reference to an object that is destroyed ... << this isn't the problem -_-

In the instruction above, and based on the reference returned by fctr the program **copy** the destroyed object *loc* into x.

In other hand, returning by value **copy** the object *loc* into x !!

The only difference I see is that when returning by reference the object *loc* is destroyed, but when returning by value the object *loc* doesn't destroyed **until the instruction is finished.**

*So returning by value seems safe and it do the same as returning by reference !!*

What I read in books and what I heard from people is that returning by reference is faster than returning by value ...

So why returning by reference is fast than returning by value ?

... I think that I'm wrong in something but I don't know what is it ?!!!

Comment: "this isn't the problem -_-" This is the problem.

Comment: It is not faster. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I know that is a problem -_-, but now I'm talking about which of the two ways is faster and why ...

Comment: Why isn't returning a reference to a temporary a problem? A copy is being made because the type of `x` is `A`; if you change it to `A& x = fctr();` no copy will be made, and you'll be referencing invalid memory thereon. Even now your program has undefined behavior because, as you note, the copy is made *after* the temporary is destroyed. Returning by reference should only be done when you know the lifetime of the backing store is greater than or equal to that of whatever is going to receive the reference.

Comment: In `fctr`, what is `a`?

Comment: when we overloading operators like + we returning a reference isn't that the same case !!

Comment: @BBeta A typical `operator+` implementation will not return a reference; I think you're confusing that with `operator+=`. For example, take a look at the signatures of various operators being overloaded by [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: There's no guarantee that returning by reference is faster. If the object only has a single integer member and no code in the copy constructor, I'd expect return by value to be faster - but not by much.

Answer (score 1):

Returning by reference - System don't need to allocate & initialise any extra memory. Just have to pass the memory address of already existing location.

Returning by value - System need to allocate & initialise extra memory.

It completely depends on the requirements whether you need "by reference" or "by value".